# How to implement Sanitize library in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

Which is best library for sanitize? As it is useful for security purpose but as we inject dependency for same in angularjs so what is best way to implement in angular6?

Comment: [a 10 seconds search on the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer) would have answered you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Import module first in your component - 

 import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 // Create object for that inside constructor like below --
 constructor(public _domSanitizationService: DomSanitizer) {}


 // In your HTML file use like below.
 <img [src]="_domSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url) />
```